# send app to background but not go to Home

Tags: android

I want to send app to back form a non-activity class

With this code ,app send to background but all other apps send to background too

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
Home.context.startActivity(i);
```

I want **only this app** send to background

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use some global stuff then you need to do some trick by which your application can't affect other applications.

A small technique for your help..Use a **KEY** for your app and save it inside a `SharedPreference`. Use this key to identify your application. And If the key is perfect then do your code.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry if I did some wrong here. But I thought this trick will help OP to filter his personal app from other apps installed in device. i just reply for "With this code ,app send to background but all other apps send to background too" sentence.